# ASP.NET 500 server errors sometimes not handled by custom error page

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have custom error pages set up as follows in the web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect" defaultRedirect="/ErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

I am expecting "500 server errors" to result in a redirect to /ErrorPage.aspx. This does generally happen except in some cases where IIS returns the following content:

500 Server Error
**An error occured during processing : if possible, check the event log of the server
Administrators : Obtain more information by changing to debug mode and switching custom errors off in the configuration**.

My problem with this is:

1. I want to control what content is shown to the user - i.e. not this "ugly" error. I have no idea what HTML template is used to generate the content - it is not the 500.htm (from %SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr) that IIS is configured to use.
2. Although it says "check the event log", I never see anything there - so I have no clues as to the source of the error

So, what could the source of this kind of error be, and how can I control the response?

(the site is ASP.NET 4.0 webforms, running on IIS7.5, using a classic-mode application pool)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Configure for `500` statusCode also use `redirectMode=ResponseRewrite` to avoid `302`

Read this <kbd>[Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/paxer/archive/2010/05/31/asp-net-http-404-and-seo.aspx)</kbd>

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On" 
     redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">

   <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>
   <error statusCode="500" redirect="ErrorPage.aspx"/>

</customErrors>
```